# How do I parse a specific section from a JSON text to make a list of heroes from League of Legends

Tags: c#, json, parsing, console-application

I'm trying to get all the names of the heroes from League of legends from a JSON url: http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json and I'm trying to get out the the name of that hero after "name": from the JSON url.

How do I get the names of all the heroes?

I tried with index and substrings but I feel like it's hardcoding

```
$public static async void GetHtml()
        {
            var url = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json ";
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);`

            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument(); 

            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

            var jsonData =  JObject.Parse(html);

            var index = jsonData.ToString().IndexOf("name", StringComparison.Ordinal);

            var champName= jsonData.ToString().Substring(index, 20);
                Console.WriteLine(champName);
        }
```

I only get one name and my goal is to get all the names of the heroes in a List. Btw I'm using JSON.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `html` variable you're trying to parse is just a JSON string.  You don't need that `HtmlDocument` at all.

In general terms you need to create a set of classes to deserialize the data into.  Since you only want part of the information you only need a minimal set of classes to describe the structure.

In JSON.net the best matching structure is a `Dictionary<,>`.  The result will have the Keys being the member names and the values being whatever record type we choose.  In this case we only care about the member names, so we can use an empty record type.

In this case, a minimal JSON representation of the parts we're interested looks something like this:

```
{
    {
        "Aatrox": { "name":"Aatrox" },
        "Ahri": { "name":"Ahri" },
        "AurelionSol": { "name":"Aurelion Sol" }
    }
}
```

Here's a minimal class structure to parse the original file into that will only capture the information we care about:

```
class ChampionsRoot
{
    public Dictionary<string, ChampionInfo> data;
}

class ChampionInfo
{
    public string name;
}
```

Now we just need some code to pull those names out of the data:

```
static void Main()
{
    var url = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json";
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var source = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;

    var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChampionsRoot>(source);
    var names = root.data.Select(kv => kv.Value.name).ToArray();
}
```

And now `names` is an array of all of the `name` values.

---

Or if you want to go regex:

```
void Main()
{
    var url = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/data/en_US/champion.json";
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var source = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).Result;

    // "name":"(value)"
    var regex = new Regex("\"name\":\"([^\"]+)\"");
    var matches = regex.Matches(source);
    var names = matches.OfType<Match>().Select(_ => _.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
}
```

There are no other `name` fields in the data, so this returns the same results as the JSON.net version just without the dependency.

Comment: One more question, how do I go from image to full if I want to get for example "Aatrox.png"? Thanks again :)

Comment: @MazzEbra You'll need another class to capture the `image` member into.  Something like `struct ChampionImage { public string full; }` and add `public ChampionImage image;` to the `ChampionInfo` class.

Comment: Thanks again mate. You are awesome <3

Comment: @MazzEbra I've thrown together a quick LINQPad script with both minimal and full versions of the classes to give you an idea.  [Check it out here.](https://gist.github.com/Corey-M/6019147149783630565a2f5cf1f4fc43)